# Typed Entities with breezejs for typescript or alternative an extension to VS to create interfaces from c# class?

Tags: typescript, breeze

I am creating a demo project using breeze/knockout in typescript.

When i have my `manager.createEntity("Project")` i get a object of type breeze.Entity returned. This have `entityAspect` and `enityType`.

I havent been able to find if it is possible to get it to return the correct type, project in my case.

Another solution, if anyone could assist in creating it, would be to have design time support in VS for c# classes in typescript.

I would then be able to do manager.createEntity("Project"); I believe that would be the best way to get types for entities in such situations. Any comments? Anyone who can create me such an extension? or tell me how.

Comment: Could you please clarify the question, not quite sure exactly what you are asking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer "I havent been able to find if it is possible to get it to return the correct type, project in my case."

The only solution you have at the moment is type assertion (Typescript alternative to type casting) ie. :

```
var myProject:Project = <Project>manager.createEntity("Project");
```

Although a new feature is on the way that makes it super simple to define such definitions. Its called ***overload on constants*** : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/03/25/working-on-typescript-0-9-generics-overload-on-constants-and-compiler-performance.aspx

Comment: is this supposed to work ? `var myProject:Project = <Project>manager.createEntity("Project");`  Because when I try, I get `Type 'Entity' cannot be converted to type 'Projectt'.
  Property 'cache' is missing in type 'Entity'.`

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a solution for "alternative an extension to VS to create interfaces from c# class?".

I don't have a VS-extension (yet), but I made a small tool which will create Knockout/Backbone/TypeScript-models/interfaces from your .NET-Domainclasses.

If you use DataAnnotations, you'll get default-values and evaluation on knockout/backbone for free :)

http://jsmapper.codeplex.com

Comment: Sounds interesting. Will take a look